# Problem with "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed" error

Tags: excel, vba

This is a question mainly to understand and learn, then to find a solution, since i know what causes the problem and made a workaround.

I get Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed.

I have a main UserForm with a ListBox, it gets filled from a table. Then i have a secondary UserForm to make new entries in said table. That table is on my sheet shData("Daten") and is called "mainData". If just run the secondary form to make new entry, all is fine. But if i start the secondary form from main form, i get the error.

This is the code in main form.

```
Private Sub newEntryButton_Click()
    newEntry.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    mainListUpdate
End Sub
```

This is the code in secondary form

```
Private Sub doneButton_Click()
    Dim n As Long
    n = cRow + 1
    shData.Range("A" & n).Value = nameBox.Value
    shData.Range("B" & n).Value = paraBox.Value
    shData.Range("C" & n).Value = hStartBox.Value
    shData.Range("D" & n).Value = bdayBox.Value
    If OptionButtonStat.Value = True Then
        shData.Range("E" & n).Value = "Ja"
        shData.Range("G" & n).Value = statPlaceBox.Value
    ElseIf OptionButtonAmb.Value = True Then
        shData.Range("F" & n).Value = "Ja"
    End If
    Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButtonStat_Change()
    If OptionButtonStat.Value = True Then
        Me.statPlaceBox.Visible = True
        Me.statPlaceLab.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.statPlaceBox.Visible = False
        Me.statPlaceLab.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.statPlaceBox.Visible = False
    Me.statPlaceLab.Visible = False
End Sub
```

and this is the code in a module.

```
Public cRow As Long
Public cCol As Long
Public Sub mainListUpdate()
    If shData.FilterMode = True Then
        shData.ShowAllData
    End If
    cRow = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 
    cCol = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    formMain.listMain.ColumnCount = cCol
    formMain.listMain.ColumnHeads = True
    formMain.listMain.RowSource = "mainData"
End Sub
```

The error occurs on the following line in secondary form code: `shData.Range("A" & n).Value = nameBox.Value`. If i change `formMain.listMain.RowSource = "mainData"` in the module code to `formMain.listMain.RowSource = "Daten!A2:G"`, the problem disappears. Again, the code works fine with the table as RowSource, if i just use the secondary form, just need to add `cRow = shData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`.

I hope, i explained it well enough. Can somebody please explain, why i have this problem? It was very frustrating to search for the issue and i really would like to use the original code.

Comment: What is the value of `n` when the error happens?

Comment: 11 and i have 10 rows in the table.

Comment: When the error occurs can you see what happens in the Immediate Window if you: `? shData.Range("a11").address`

Comment: If i put that just before `shData.Range("A" & n).Value = nameBox.Value`, then the error occurs in that line. When i hover with mouse over that line, i see `shData.Range("a11").Address = "$A$11"`

Comment: Honestly, I think something may be wrong with your Office installation. Can you try running this workbook on a different computer to see if the problem is reproducible?

Comment: I could try it in like 1 hour on the office pc with older excel.

Comment: What is the value of `nameBox.Value` at the time of the failing assignment?

Comment: some random keyboard smash like"dfwfasda" or "test" or a random number

Comment: Ok, tested in on the office PC and it works fine. So my home excel needs to be reinstalled.